# Why can't this Spring Boot application find the main page?

Tags: java, maven, reactjs, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to create a minimal Spring Boot application that allows me to use
ReactJS on the frontend.

**What I want to achieve**

When I run the Spring Boot application, it should display a page with a React
component inside it.

**Structure of the project**

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/dpisarenko/minimal-react-boot-project).

- [Spring Boot application class](https://github.com/dpisarenko/minimal-react-boot-project/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/mycompany/MyApp.kt)
- [Controller](https://github.com/dpisarenko/minimal-react-boot-project/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/mycompany/HomeController.kt) class
- Main [HTML page](https://github.com/dpisarenko/minimal-react-boot-project/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/index.html)
- [React Code](https://github.com/dpisarenko/minimal-react-boot-project/blob/master/src/main/js/app.js)

**What I get**

When I

1. run `mvn clean`mvn clean spring-boot:run` and
2. navigate to `http://localhost:8080`,

I get the 404 error (see below).

[image: Error message]

How can I fix it?

Notes:

1. I copied the approach from the tutorial [React.js and Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/).
2. Don't tell me to get rid of Kotlin, it's very unlikely that it's Kotlin that
   causes the problem.

**Update 1 (07.08.2017 22:17 MSK):**

The output of `mvn clean spring-boot:run` can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/288a8f4d53d6e8254af1ae96ae5713cc).

**Update 2 (07.08.2017 22:44 MSK):**

Changing `RestController` to `Controller` in `MyApp` class and moving the `main`
method inside it didn't help.

Currently, the `MyApp` class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
open class MyApp {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp::class.java,*args)
    }
}
```

Comment: What messages do you see on the console (where you typed the `mvn` command)? Do you see "server started" etc?

Comment: Ad *Do you see "server started" etc?*: Yes. I've included the output of `mvn clean spring-boot:run` in update 1.

Comment: Please don't link your errors and output. Copy them in here and format them properly so the links don't change or expire later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now I don't have experince in Kotlin but I can tell you that you are missing something in the following code (in addition to having an extra `RestController` annotation ).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
open class MyApp {

}
```

In Java this class implements `ServletContextInitializer` in addition to having the `main` within it with the following static method run:

```
SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
```

I hope this helps.

## Update

Try to also add a template resolving bean, now it is not the only way to do this but worths a try that would look like the following:

```
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver yourTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver yourTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    yourTemplateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
   return yourTemplateResolver;
}
```

and add the following lines to your application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

don't forget to import thymeleaf to your POM:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: He is expecting a page. So `@RestController` is not the proper annotation in this use case. Should use `@Controller` instead.

Comment: actually in the controller he used the `controller` annotation see here: https://github.com/dpisarenko/minimal-react-boot-project/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/mycompany/HomeController.kt but in the application initializer and RestController....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but it didn't help (see update 2).

Comment: can you please try adding `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` bean although it is from Thymeleaf but since you added your templates to `sources` folder I assume you need to add a template resolver. check the answer's update.

Comment: was a little late :) check it now.

Comment: @MrMisery Thanks, your answer helped. The GitHub repo now contains a version that works for me (with your changes being there).